# Cannot convert Array to Odject[][] Even though it is a 2D array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Still new and just learning how to use arrays. I am getting the error "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line 46, file "Submit to Record")

Line 46 is

```
  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, arrayOfData.length).setValues(arrayOfData);
```

I had this error once before, but it was because of an array inside an array issue. Now I don't know what's wrong.

The entire code is

```
function submitButtonClick() {   

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  Logger.log('sheet.getName(): ' + sheet.getName());


  if (sheet.getName() !== "SubmitReceipt") {return;};

  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ReceiptRecord");

  var arrayOfData = [];

  var week = sheet.getRange(6,9).getValue();
  var emplN = sheet.getRange(4,9).getValue();
  var purDate = sheet.getRange(9,9).getValue();
  var purFrom = sheet.getRange(11,9).getValue();
  var custC = sheet.getRange(14,9).getValue();
  var deptC = sheet.getRange(16,9).getValue();
  var lotC = sheet.getRange(18,9).getValue();
  var laborC = sheet.getRange(20,9).getValue();
  var itemC = sheet.getRange(22,9).getValue();
  var hyperL = sheet.getRange(28,9).getValue();
  var notes = sheet.getRange(44,8).getValue();

  arrayOfData[0] = week;
  arrayOfData[1] = emplN;
  arrayOfData[2] = purDate;
  arrayOfData[3] = purFrom;
  arrayOfData[4] = custC;
  arrayOfData[5] = deptC;
  arrayOfData[6] = lotC;
  arrayOfData[7] = laborC;
  arrayOfData[8] = itemC;
  arrayOfData[9] = hyperL;
  arrayOfData[10] = notes;

  Logger.log('arrayOfData '+ arrayOfData)

  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();

  Logger.log('lastRow: ' + lastRow);
  Logger.log('arraylength ' + arrayOfData.length);

  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, arrayOfData.length).setValues(arrayOfData);

  sheet.getRange(6,9).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(4,9).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(9,9).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(11,9).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(14,9).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(16,9).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(18,9).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(20,9).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(22,9).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(28,9).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(44,8).clearContent();

}
```

I know this code is clunky and could be written more efficiently and condensed, but I am writing this way on purpose because I am new to JS and this is an easy way for me to keep my head on straight about what is happening in the code. I hope my sanity efforts are not the cause of my problem. Please help.  :)

Comment: Could you show the logger.log result ? I guess you should simply write `setValues([arrayOfData])` but I'm just guessing ;-)

Comment: You were correct! That's all it needed. Thanks so much for an observant set of eyes.

Comment: you're welcome:). Your array was a simple array, `setValues()` needs an array of arrays, even for a single row of data.

Comment: I think I get it, it had to be a 1 item array containing an array of multiple items that then fill in the multiple cells. Is that correct?

Comment: yes. btw, I allowed myself to edit your question a bit... I removed the javascript tag because this is strictly specific to Google Apps script and removed the "run snippet" gadget since in can obviously not be executed from witihn this site. I hope you won't mind. I also upvoted to compensate the -1 that came probably from the "pure javascript" forum ;-)

Comment: The 2D array corresponds to an array of arrays, each cell in a row is an element of the row array and each row is an element of the upper level array. A single cell would be shown like that :[[value]], that's to say one row array in a one column array.

Answer (score 1):

Serge insas answered the question in the comments. He said:

I guess you should simply write

```js
setValues([arrayOfData])
```

but I'm just guessing ;-)"

That did indeed fix the problem. Thanks, Serge insas!